# How can you check multiple index using charAt() method in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to compare two string-arrays from a .txt file input based on the index of a char.

```
So String1[i] is not complete -> example: B_nana.

String2[j] is the fitting word for string 1 -> Banana
```

If the program finds a matching index, for example -> both have "a" at index 1, it checks for the string length and if that matches aswell it replaces `String1[i] = String2[j].`

But everytime the `charAt()` index exceeds the length of a string while comparing (one of the strings is shorter than the other), I get `StringOutOfBoundException`.

So my question is, is there any way to compare not only one index of two strings but all of them?
I already tried using

`string.substring(0, str.length -1)` but thats not working at all.

Grateful for any suggestions and if you need more information to answer my question please feel free to say so.

Comment: Take a step back, forget Java, and write down in plain old English what it is you exactly want to do. Are you trying to find words that match a given pattern?

Comment: I am given a textfile containing 2 lines of strings. Line 1 is made of blanked strings which have blanks somewhere inside the string like 'ap_le'. Line 2 contains the fitting words without any blanks like 'apple'. My goal is to compare each string from line 2 to each blanked string from line 1 and find a match.

Comment: So by "match" do you mean all the characters are the same except for the "\_"?  How many "\_" are allowed?  What happens if the entire first string consists of nothing but "\_"?

Comment: Yes ,all characters are the same except for the underscore. I did not think about what should happen if there are only "_" yet.

Comment: Have a look at the sample I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I would do the following:

1. Build a list of valid words (List knownWords)
2. Build a list of words with gaps (List guessWords)

Here is some pseudo code

- For each word in guessWords:

  - while (!match && has more words in knownWords)

    - set match to false
    - compare the length of the current guess word to the nth word in know words
    - if they have the same length, compare each character. If each character from the known word is equal to each character of the guess word or if the guess word's character is _ then match = true

This should put you on the right track

### Sample source code (Java)

```
package eu.webfarmr;

/**
 * This class takes in 2 lists (or arrays) and tries to match words from the first array to words in the second
 * the underscore (_) is considered to be a missing letter.
 * @author dbrossard
 *
 */
public class WordMatcher {
    private final static String[] knownWords = {"apple", "arcane", "batter", "butter", "banana"};
    private final static String[] guessWords = {"a___e","a____e","__tte_","b_____"};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String guessWord : guessWords) {
            boolean matchFound = false;
            int i = 0;
            while (!matchFound && i < knownWords.length) {
                if (guessWord.length()==knownWords[i].length()) {
                    int j = 0;
                    while (j < guessWord.length() && (guessWord.charAt(j)==knownWords[i].charAt(j) || guessWord.charAt(j)=='_') ) {
                        j++;
                    }
                    matchFound = (j == guessWord.length());
                    if (matchFound) {
                        System.out.println(guessWord + " matches " + knownWords[i]);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to find all matches and not just the first one change `while (!matchFound && i < knownWords.length) {` to `while (i < knownWords.length) {`.

Here is sample output:

```
a___e matches apple
a____e matches arcane
__tte_ matches batter
__tte_ matches butter
b_____ matches batter
b_____ matches butter
b_____ matches banana
```

Comment: Thanks! I did all of this except that I do not know how to compare each character. If it is comparing knowWord having its max index at 2 to guessWord having its max index at 6, I get a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2". How do I solve this?

Comment: while (match & i < maskedWord.length) {
    match = maskedWord[i] == knownWord[i]
}

Comment: Did the sample code help?